# vb.net console app merge unknown number of XML files, problems adding to collection

Tags: xml, vb.net, merge, array-merge

I am trying to create an app that allows the user to drag/drop files into a console. The console feeds the paths through a mediator into a collection of `XmlTextReader`s which in turn fill up a `DataSet` collection  in a for loop based on an `XmlReader` collection `.count` and finally merge the whole thing.
Well everything is nice and dandy until I try to `.add` to `XmlTextReader` list, then it throws a `NullReferenceException` in the form of [error report from vbstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSVGM.png)

I've tried to investigate but just don't get it.
The code below has, I hope, all the necessary information.

```
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String
        Dim nl As String = Environment.NewLine
        Dim xml_files As List(Of XmlTextReader)
        Dim xml_ds As List(Of DataSet)
        Dim ds_sum As DataSet

        Do While input <> "merge"
            Console.WriteLine("--- drag & drop file to  be merged---" + nl)
            input = Console.ReadLine()
            If input <> "merge" Then 
                Dim xml__ As New XmlTextReader(input)
                xml_files.Add(xml__) ' this is th plce that throws the exception 
                'xml_files.Add(New XmlTextReader(input))  something i tried
                Console.WriteLine(nl & "--- drag & drop new file or order  merge ---" & nl)
            ElseIf input = "merge" Then
                ' ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼  read datasets to collection ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
                For i = 0 To xml_files.Count - 1
                    Dim ds As New DataSet ' mediator
                    ds.ReadXml(xml_files(i)) ' read one-by-one xml 
                    xml_ds.Add(ds) 'i ubacuje u kolekciju xml_ds
                Next
            End If
        Loop
        ' ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ovde sad ide XML MERGE ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
        ds_sum = xml_ds(0)

        For i = 1 To xml_ds.Count
            ds_sum.Merge(xml_ds(i))
        Next
        ' ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ispis xml-a ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
        Console.WriteLine(nl & "--- direktorijum u koji zelis da sacuvas sabrani XML Prevuci u terminal ---" & nl)
        input = Console.ReadLine()
        ds_sum.WriteXml(input)
    End Sub
End Module
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try changing   Dim xml_files As List(Of XmlTextReader) to   Dim xml_files As new List(Of XmlTextReader)

Comment: Thanks, that has done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim xml_files As List(Of XmlTextReader)
```

only declares xml_files as an object that can contain objects that are lists of XmlTextReaders. It doesn't initialize it. In longhand you would type

```
Dim xml_files As List(Of XmlTextReader) = New List(Of XmlTextReader)
```

which declares the object and assigns to it a new initialized list, but you can write

```
Dim xml_files As New List(Of XmlTextReader)
```

which accomplishes exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation, after alteration to my code the whole thing works the way i intended it to.